# Uploading to s3, with success callback on iOS

Tags: ios, ios7, file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This question perhaps can be trivial, be as I am starting with IOS I'm not sure on what to search for.

I have a backend which handles processing of images, and with browser-based uploads, the images get upload directly to a temp folder in the app's bucket in S3, once done, I send the url to the backend for processing of the image in a background worker.

On IOS, I don't understand how and who is responsible for getting the url of the just-uploaded file to the server or to the app along with some meta data (which user uploaded the file, etc)

Looking at an S3 SDK for mobile example https://aws.amazon.com/articles/3002109349624271 I don't see that this is included.

Is that possible? Is that a common practice to do (get the url back from S3 and send it to the server along with meta data)?

Comment: where is your web-services hosted? on Amazon server?

Comment: heroku, so yes - amazon. Why is it relevant?

Comment: If you are uploading it on S3 then you have to get the URL of that image and send it to the server which is reponsible of doing the processing. The content is saved in key value form so instead of sending a URL you can send the key to the server and your server can get the image from the S3 bucket using that key and process the image.

Comment: yes, but I'm stuck one step before that. How do I get the key? Who holds it? When do I get it from S3?

Comment: You are going to store the image to S3 with that key it means you hold that key. Once it will be uploaded successfully you can send that key to the server.

Comment: ok, how can I know it uploaded successfully?

Comment: Let me post an answer

Comment: Answer posted. Please accept the answer if it is helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample code from link in question.

```
S3PutObjectRequest *putObjectRequest = [[[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:MY_PICTURE_NAME inBucket:MY_PICTURE_BUCKET] autorelease];
putObjectRequest.contentType = @"image/jpeg";
putObjectRequest.data = imageData;

// Now we need to get the response and check the error which was not in the sample code given in the link
S3PutObjectResponse *putObjectResponse = [s3 putObject:putObjectRequest]; 
if (!putObjectResponse.error)
{
    // Send the KEY to server.
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.